# Circular dependencies with headers. Using #ifndef and #define

Tags: c++

I have the very simple following code:

main.cpp

```
#include "ui_library_browser.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "StartWindow.h"
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  StartWindow w;
  w.show();
  return a.exec();
}
```

StartWindow.h

```
#ifndef STARTWINDOW_H_
#define STARTWINDOW_H_

#include <qwidget>
#include "MainWindow.h"

class StartWindow : public QWidget
{ 
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  StartWindow();
  ~StartWindow();
  MainWindow main_window;  //<-- Problem
};
#endif
```

MainWindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H_
#define MAINWINDOW_H_

#include <qdialog.h>
#include "StartWindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MainWindow();
  ~MainWindow();
};
#endif
```

This produces errors because of the inclusion of #include "StartWindow.h" in the MainWindow.h header.  However, I thought the use of #ifndef and #define are to stop problems like this?  Can someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Exactly what errors are you getting? Although it's dependent on the order in which of your headers is first included and so probably needs fixing anyway, as you include `StartWindow.h` _first_, the code you've posted ought to be OK (assuming you have all the Qt things correct).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So called "header guards" are used to prevent a bit different kind of error: including same header multiple time through different indirect inclusions in one compile unit. For example, 
you include "a.h" from main.cpp and then include "b.h" from main.cpp, that includes "a.h" itself somewhere inside.

In your case two headers try to include each other circurally, that is not possible - C/C++ preprocessor works as simple text "copy-paste" and this case would invent infinite recursion of text insertion.

And I really don't see why would you need "StartWindow.h" inclusion in "MainWindow.h" header.

Comment: Oh, by the way I was way too impatient and after closer examination and test can say that similar code compiles fine for me ( as it should ). Header guard should apply indeed.

Could you post your error message?

Comment: The reason I want to have "StartWindow.h" inclusion in "MainWindow.h" header is because I want to have a pointer as reference to the StartWindow class, passed through in the MainWindow constructor.

Comment: Than you need an extern declaration of StartWindow class in MainWindow.h - without header inclusion. You see, header guard actually works - so nothing will be included in MainWindow.h in practice. Probably it is the real problem you have in your full code. Still, error message would help.

Comment: Oh, in fact you dont even need extern decl - just forward decl, only class is needed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you use StartWindow in MainWindow? If not, simply remove the StartWindow.h include. Otherwise make the main_window a pointer instead of a variable.

Comment: I think OP is well aware of this obvious solution.  OP is asking why the `STARTWINDOW_H_` macro is not already defined when the second `#include` directive takes place.

Answer (score 1):

In the file StartWindow.h remove `#include "MainWindow.h"` and add the forward declaration (before `class StartWindow ...`):

```
class MainWindow;
```

In the same file change the member `MainWindow main_window` to

```
const MainWindow* main_window;
```

or

```
const MainWindow& main_window;
```

In the latter case you would need to pass  `const MainWindow&` in the constructor of `StartWindow`.