# Header file imports acting strangely

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circular dependencies with headers. Using #ifndef and #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573878/circular-dependencies-with-headers-using-ifndef-and-define)

I try to import a header file that contains a class that extends to class in that header file and it doesn't work :S

TileGrass.h:

```
#ifndef TILEGRASS_H_
#define TILEGRASS_H_

#include "Tile.h"

class TileGrass : public Tile
{
    public:
        TileGrass(unsigned char);
};

#endif /* TILEGRASS_H_ */
```

Tile.h:

```
#ifndef TILE_H_
#define TILE_H_

class Tile
{
    public:
        Tile(unsigned char);
        unsigned char id;
};

#include "TileGrass.h"

extern Tile* tiles[256];
TileGrass tileGrass = TileGrass(0);

#endif /* TILE_H_ */
```

Doing this gives me the error:
error: 'TileGrass' does not name a type

Comment: Ive edited that into the bottom now, sorry :S

Comment: Re *Doing this gives me the error: error: 'TileGrass' does not name a type* -- Where? There's some code that you aren't showing. Show it! (Preferably just enough to reproduce the error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first glance, I see two errors:

- a circular include which isn't necessary (`Tile.h` doesn't need to include `TileGrass.h` - you can just re-organize the file to remove the include)
- `TileGrass tileGrass = TileGrass(0);` is a definition, and it's in a header, so you'll get a multiple definition error if you include the header multiple times. If you want a global (**rethink that**), you have to use `extern`.

Comment: It does need to include TileGrass.h otherwise it cant do the TileGrass tileGrass = TileGrass(0);    And i realise that is shouldn't define it in the header :)

Comment: @user1956056 no, it doesn't **need to** because you don't **need to** declare `tileGrass` in that file... You can move it to `TileGrass.h`.

Comment: Hmmm... i supose, but i was hoping to be able to declare tileGrass in that file

Comment: @user1956056 nope. Nor should there be. It makes no sense for it to be declared there. A base class should have no knowledge of derived objects or classes.

Comment: @user1956056 - Why? It's a sign of code smell.